# Are there any differences between distributions (generalized functions) and probability distributions?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, distribution-theory

A distribution/generalized function is an element of the dual space of $$S=\{f\in  C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\colon \|f\|_{\alpha,\beta}<\infty \text{ for all } \alpha ,\beta\}$$
Where $\|f\|_{\alpha,\beta}=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|x^{\alpha} f^{(\beta)}(x)|$. We know that all probability measures are elements of $S^*$, or more specifically the linear functional $L_{\mu}\colon S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $L_{\mu} (f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fd\mu$.

In this sense, a probability measure is just a linear functional $L\colon S\cup\{1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $L(1)=1$.

Using the Riesz Representation Theorem, any linear functional (with a few technical considerations) has a unique associated measure. So if $L$ is any distribution on $S\cup \{1\}$, where $L(1)=1$, it is a probability distribution.

Is this correct? A "probability distribution" (in the sense of the Radon-Nikodym derivative of a probability measure with respect to Lebesgue measure) is really just a normalized (or is uniquely associated with a) normalized Schwartz distribution?

Comment: Just $L(1) = 1$ certainly isn't enough, because it doesn't tell you anything about the local behavior of the associated signed measure; it could conceivably assign some measurable set negative measure. A positive measure has to satisfy $\int f \, d\mu \geq 0$ for all $f \geq 0$. This corresponds to the positivity of the functional $L_\mu$ (which might be one of the "technical considerations" you mentioned).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue here which is that $\mathcal{S}\cup\{1\}$ is not a vector space so we can't talk about *linear* functionals on $\mathcal{S}\cup \{1\}$. If $f\in\mathcal{S}-\{0\}$, then $f+1\notin\mathcal{S}\cup \{1\}$.

And even if we change the question by instead taking the vector space generated by $\mathcal{S}$ and $1$ and defining the topology blah blah. We could still define something like $$L:=\delta_1+\delta_2-\delta_3$$ Which will be a linear functional on your space and we'll have $L(1)=1$, but I am sure you will agree this is not a probability measure.

Answer (score 5):

The derivative of the delta "function" is a distribution but not a probability measure; to make $L(1)=1$, add your favorite probability distribution to it.  For example, $\delta'(x)+\delta(x)$.

Comment: Yeah, not every distribution is a probability measure. But is it correct to think of ANY distribution with $L(1)=1$ as a probability measure?